# C# - DataGridView - Breaking out of for loop without being told to

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface, datagridview

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn()
    {
        Name = COLUMNS.ElementAt(i).Key,
        HeaderText = COLUMNS.ElementAt(i).Value,
        Width = 60
    };
    operationsDataGridView.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

I hope it's clear enough, I'm looping through a Dictionary of **Column Name** and **Column Headers**, and adding them as *DataGridViewColumn* instances to the DataGridView.

---

However, the program is looping only once, when it should loop **9** times (I've already debugged it, and COLUMNS.Count is, in fact, *9*)

Therefore, only the first column is added, as it can be seen in the image:

[image: One Column Added]

As for the debugging output, these strange messages appear:

[image: Debugging Output]

I'm sure ***it has something to do*** with this problem.

---

#### Interesting Fact!

If I change my code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS.Count; i++)
{
    operationsDataGridView.Columns.Add(COLUMNS.ElementAt(i).Key,
                                       COLUMNS.ElementAt(i).Value);
}
```

(Which I think, is *esentially* the same), the program works **fine**!!

[image: Many Columns Added]

Comment: It's not my asnwer to the question, it's just an interesting fact. I do want to know why this strange bahivour happens

Comment: Your output is only showing 1 column, but when you step through your loop, is it going through 9 times and just displaying 1? Or does it only iterate once?

Comment: It iterates only once :(

Comment: The code you have provided doesn't work as is - I could not add a plain DataGridViewColumn, but instead needed to add either a particular type (like TextBoxColumn) or to assign the cell template. Also, when I do that, the rest of you code functions perfectly. Have you changed some settings that you don't mention? And have you tried to reproduce this in a minimal version, with just the above code and the grid on a form?

Comment: I have not tried to reproduce it in a minified version, I will proceed to try and keep you in touch. Also, I didn't touch any settings at all (I hope so!)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this error on my end, but I was getting an exception as well about "At least one of the DataGridView control's columns has no cell template."

If you change your loop to `DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()` it will probably work (fixed it on my end at least). Looks like the `.add` method with the two parameters defaults to this type of column.